# Unable to force https using htaccess on nginx server

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have been trying to force https using htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But somehow it isn't working. Only if I manually use `https://domain.name` I get the padlock sign else its always `http`.

What might be the possible reason?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enable on your server? if not enable `allowoveride mod_rewrite` for your web directory.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar  Yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Can you provide a test link if possible?

Comment: uphancer.com is my site

Comment: I am getting https.

Comment: strange..every browser of mine shows me http. My friend is also getting http.

Comment: Please clear cache on your browser and your friend's browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204768/discussion-between-ayan-and-abhishek-gurjar).